# Using QGIS in a Conda environment

Tags: qgis, python, conda

I have installed QGIS in a Conda virtual environment called qgis_stable. When I open Python in the terminal and try to run:

`import gqis.core`

I get the error message:

> ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The file "libGL.so.1" is located here: "/projects/conda/env/qgis_stable/x86_64_conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib64". I tried adding this directory to my sys.path but this did not fix the problem. Any suggestions to resolve this?

Comment: Linux looks in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for shared libs, not `PATH` https://stackoverflow.com/a/21173918

Comment: Thanks! Doing:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/projects/conda/env/qgis_stable/x86_64_conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH 

solved the issue.